# undefined is not a function React-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.login.bind(this).then(( )=> {this.navigate("Sikayet")})}  style={styles.button}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>GİRİŞ</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

[when clicked it gives this error. What should I do?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Ffn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    this.login().then(() => {
      this.navigate("Sikayet")
    })
  }}
  style={styles.button}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>GİRİŞ</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Alternatively, to clean it up a little bit, within your `login` function, take care of the navigate part there, like so:

```
// in render function:
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={this.login.bind(this)}
  style={styles.button}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>GİRİŞ</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

// in login function:
login() {
  otherFunction(email, password).then(() => {
    this.navigate("Sikayet")
  }).catch(error => {
    // invalid login credentials
    alert('Invalid email and password')
  })
}
```

Comment: it made an error again. I specified in the answer the mistakes.